# When downloading a Rom on NOTE 4 questions

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

Now I unlocked my phone  from T-mobile switched carriers to AT&T, my question is when downloading a rom do I download of N910T still or something different? In my phone setting it reads N910T... Even though I'm on AT&T now.

Comment: Even if the phone is originally from t-mobile and after i unlocked the phone to a new carrier it  still says N910T/ Should I use N910A?

Answer (score 0):

It seems These are Have different Roms.

**Galaxy Note 4 Models:**

> ```
> T-Mobile SM-N910T Galaxy Note 4
> Sprint SM-N910P Galaxy Note 4
> AT&T SM-N910A Galaxy Note 4
> Verizon SM-N910V Galaxy Note 4
> Canadian Rogers SM-N910W8 Galaxy Note 4
> Canadian Bell SM-N910W8 Galaxy Note 4
> Canadian Telus SM-N910W8 Galaxy Note 4
> International SM-N910F Galaxy Note 4
> International SM-N910C Galaxy Note 4
> ```

and According to list, you need `SM-N910A Galaxy Note 4` Rom for `AT&T`.
hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I went against what you said install the ROM that was originally for tmobile and it works perfectly I'm glad I didn't listen to you and brick my phone.